# ActiveScaffold Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting a really strange error with ActiveScaffold and Rails 4. I created a brand new project, ran "rake db:create" and "bundle install", then added the gem active_scaffold to my gem file and run "bundle install" again. Everything works fine at this point.

Then, when I try to put in:

```
rails g active_scaffold Test test:string
```

I get:

```
/Users/rgrzesik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/active_scaffold-3.2.20/lib/active_scaffold.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': This version of ActiveScaffold requires Rails 3.1 or higher.  Please use an earlier version. (RuntimeError)
from /Users/rgrzesik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
from /Users/rgrzesik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /Users/rgrzesik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
from /Users/rgrzesik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
from /Users/rgrzesik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
from /Users/rgrzesik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
from /Users/rgrzesik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
from /Users/rgrzesik/Documents/Rails_Projects/FingertipFormulary/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/rgrzesik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:44:in `require'
from /Users/rgrzesik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:44:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

What gives? I'm running Rails 4, which is way beyond Rails 3.1. Any ideas?

Comment: The latest version of ActiveScaffold is 3.3.3, so try a `bundle update`.

Comment: Actually forget that. I did a little experiment in a Rails 4 environment and it installed 3.2.20. Installing ActiveScaffold via gem install brought in Rails 3 dependencies (but 3.3.0 of ActiveScaffold...which I'm guessing is for Rails 3 only). Time to go check out the gemspec file and documentation...

Comment: Yea I just tried that too. Forced 3.3.3 in my gem file but got the error:
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    active_scaffold (~> 3.3.3) ruby depends on
      rails (~> 3.2.0) ruby

    rails (4.0.0)

Comment: If I do a `gem specification active_scaffold --version 3.2.20`, the summary line says `Rails 3.1 Version of activescaffold supporting prototype and jquery`. This may be accurate or it may just be an out of date summary string.

Comment: Aha! The summary of the latest gemspec in github is `Rails 3.2 and 4.0 version of activescaffold supporting prototype and jquery`.

Comment: Yea exactly, and the issue on Rails 4 support was closed because it should be fully compatible now. Don't really understand why it's not working

Comment: It looks like there is no release version containing that Rails 4 support. You can always try the current version from github: `gem 'active_scaffold', github: 'activescaffold/active_scaffold', branch: 'master'`

Comment: (Of course, who knows what madness may lay within) (actually, seemed to work fine for me)

Comment: awesome! that did it. any idea what problems i might run into in the future if i put it into my gem file this way?

Comment: You would continually have the very latest stuff from the master branch (possibly broken, or at least not 'satisfaction guaranteed'). (I'd said it was 'basically just a generator so it should be safe to use it then remove it' there, that wasn't quite accurate.) You should just keep an eye out for the next proper release, or avoid using it.

Comment: ok that makes sense. thanks so much! really appreciate all the help! ps: you should post an answer so i could accept your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is no release version yet containing that Rails 4 support. You can always try your luck with the current version from github: `gem 'active_scaffold', github: 'activescaffold/active_scaffold', branch: 'master'`

You can then keep an eye out for the release of 3.4.0 proper. For the meantime you would continually have the very latest stuff from the master branch (possibly broken, or at least not 'satisfaction guaranteed').